# JSON in client different from JSON returned by Rails server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to this controller method:

```
def search_posts
  keyword = params[:keyword]

  results = @client.query("SELECT * 
    FROM posts
    WHERE keyword = '#{keyword}'")

  posts = []

  results.each do |row|
    posts << {
      media_id: row["media_id"],
      media_type: row["media_type"],
      caption: row["caption"]
    }
  end

  @client.close
  render json: posts
end
```

and my JavaScript looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/search_posts',
  type: "get",
  data: {
    keyword: keyword            
  },
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

However, when I console.log the returned JSON, some of the media_ids are one less than the real value. For example, a media_id that should be `17924518156307537` is logged in the browser as `17924518156307536`.

I have `puts`'d the `posts` hash just before the `render json:` line and the media_ids are correct at that point. What's very strange is that it only happens to some media_ids, not all.

Comment: Are you converting any strings to integer?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out: JavaScript only supports up to 53-bit integers and some of the media_ids were larger than that. Solved this by converting the media_ids to strings in Ruby before sending them to the client.